# Javascript function for adding row to html table does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I developed two javascript functions which create a html table (showList4() ) and which add rows (addRow() ), pls see code below. showList4() works fine, but addRow() does not; addRow() adds row, but:

(error 1): the row is not added straight under the previous row, but shifted to the left.

(error 2): executing addRow the second time does not put the row after/under the previously added row, but before/above it.

For adding a row I looked at the solution at [Add table row in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery) but I dont know where I go wrong with the addRow() code?

javascript code:

```
function showList4(title, wrapper, wrappermethod, tableid){ //this functions works fine

   if((!$('#'+wrapper).length) ){//no action if no info or invalid wrapper agurment type
        return;
   }//if

   var form = '<table id="'+tableid+'">';

   //add title
   if(typeof title === 'string'){
       form += '<caption> '+ title +' </caption>';
   }//if
   form += '<tbody>';
   var nrofrows = arguments.length - 4;
   console.log('Showlist3- nrofrows: '+nrofrows)
   //add following rows with vert labels in first colum and datavalues in following columns
   for(var row=0;row<nrofrows;row++){ //for each following row 
       form += '<tr> <td> ';
       for(var column=0, column_max=arguments[4+row].length;column<column_max;column++){
           if(arguments[4+row] !== undefined){
                form += '<td>' + arguments[4+row][column] + ' </td>';
           }//if
       }//for(var column=0, column_max=labels_hori.length;column<column_max;column++){
       form += '</tr>';
   }//for(var i=0,i_max=labels_hori.length;i<i_max;i++

   form += '<tr><td> </tr></td> </tbody> </table>'; //add empty line and finish table

   switch(wrappermethod){
       case 'html':
           $('#'+wrapper).html(form);
           break;
       default: //no action if invalid wrapper argument
           break;
   };//switch
   return;

};//showList4()

function addRow(tableid,values){
   var form = '<tr>';
   for(var i=0,i_max=values.length;i<i_max;i++){
       form += '<td>' + values[i] + '</td>';
   }//for
   form += '</tr>';

   $('#'+tableid+' > tbody:last').after(form); //reference example code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery
   //$('#'+tableid+' tr:last').after(form); //reference example code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery
   return;
}//addrow


$(document).ready(function(){

        showList4('Title table','myDivid','html','myTable',
                      ['Some text1','Some text2','Some text3','Some text4'],
                      ['1','2','3','4']);

        addRow('myTable',['A','B','C','D']);
        addRow('myTable',['E','F','G','H']);

});//$(document).ready(function(){
```

html code:

```
<div id="myDivid" style="width:500px; "> </div>
```

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work?... I've copy&pasted your code and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/eyanez/JSKXc/

Comment: It works in the sense that the 2 rows with figure are added below the first row. But your jsfiddle also shows that the added rows are down left to the first row, e.g., the letters E and A are not straight under '1'. Also, after row [1,2,3,4] I would/want expect row [A,B,C,D], not [E,F,G,H] as also illustrated by your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

First, you are targeting the "last body tag" rather than the "last row in the body". So change your line

```
$('#'+tableid+' > tbody:last').after(form);
```

to

```
$('#'+tableid+' > tbody > tr:last').after(form);
```

This will ensure that the new row is inserted within the `body` of the table.

Second, you are creating an additional cell in your first two rows. See this line

```
form += '<tr> <td> ';
```

Change it to

```
form += '<tr>';
```

Third, you have broken html on this line

```
form += '<tr><td> </tr></td> </tbody> </table>'; //add empty line and finish table
```

Change it to

```
form += '<tr><td colspan="4"></td></tr></tbody> </table>'; //add empty line and finish table. NOTE the colspan to format the table correctly.
```

Here is a working version at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nakicodi/1/edit)

p.s. jsbin suggest some other fixes to missing semi-colons, misuse of the switch statement and unnecessary semi-colons.

Comment: awesome, thnx Tim (!).

Comment: once I found jsbin I forgot about jsfiddle :P